# Mavlink data parsing offline from buffer, on Linux in C

Tags: c, mavlink

I am a beginner with mavlink and even pixahawk.
I need to just parse mavlink data coming from pixahawk. (Mavlink v1, pixahawk v5plus), on Linux PC (Ubuntu). I have 2 processes in context of this question. (The Pixahwak is already cofigured to send some messages HEARTBEAT, ATTITUDE etc).

I have written C code that reads serial port data which gets mavlink v1 data from telemetry1 port of pixhackv5plus and saves each byte by byte in shared memory segment created using *shmget()/shmat()*. That shared memory segment remains intact even after this process exits.

Now, I run another process that reads data from this shared memory buffer and parses byte by byte. This parser process has not been completely written by me but I took code from
*https://github.com/mavlink/c_uart_interface_example* and for mavlink v1, reusing c library from *https://github.com/mavlink/c_library_v1* (My pixahawk sends Mavlink v1 data).
In file ***serial_port.cpp*** in c uart example above, I have removed code that calls ***read(fd..)*** but taking shared memory data byte by byte and passing to ***mavlink_parse_char()***.
This is not working, I am getting ***msgReceived*** as ***false*** through out, though I know
this data contains valid mavlink messages.

Am I right in this methodology? 
Please guide. Once this works, I have to replicate parser on an embedded platform, in C.

Code for reading serial data from pixhack at:
***https://github.com/developb/mavlink_read_buffer/blob/master/main_rx.c***

Code where data(each byte) is read from shared memory and fed to mavlink_parse_char() is at:
***https://github.com/developb/mavlinkv1_parse_v0/blob/master/serial_port.cpp***

Here, this is the line I modify that makes each byte be taken from shared memory instead of serial port:

```
 int result = _read_port(cp);
 //cp = (unsigned char)(*(unsigned char*)shm_current_addr_temp);
```

Comment: Most would do this using file io. Particularly on Linux where all the infrastructure is designed around file manipulation. Is there a reason you are using shared memory? Why not a pipe? Why not dump to storage and read from storage?

Comment: Shared memory gives more control, so I used that. I can run read and buffer as a process, and then parse as another process independently.I can make sure I don't miss any byte due to any processing latency and focus on buffering data to get each and every byte. I can at any point of time use gdb and check by debugging, the values in shared memory...

Comment: You'll get better help if you link your code.

Comment: Does the embedded platform you eventually want to use support this kind of "shared memory" ?

Answer (score 0):

To use file parsing functions with in-memory data, you need to make sure the memory layout matches the file layout.

Likely problem sources are leaving out header info or using data structures optimized for memory (all c structures that have not been packed) when providing data to the parser.

Comment: I have copied each byte as it arrives to shm (checked sequence number of messages). The header byte __(0xfe)__ is also copied into shm as is. So, it should be same as receiving data from serial port directly. I will have to delve deeper into code to resolve this, as I have reused existing code. I wanted to confirm my methodology is correct or not in achieving offline parsing, and any inputs are welcome, to do it in C specifically.